# onDestroy called when starting app in emulator

Tags: android

I am starting up my app in the emulator and seeing a call to `onDestroy()` on the starting activity. Android doc seems to suggest that `onDestroy()` is called only when the app is stopped. Are there other circumstances when it can be called? It causes a problem for my app because I am shutting down an executor in the `onDestroy()` method (which was created at class loading time). The first attempt to use the executor then throws a `RejectedExecutionException`. I'm guessing this is because I have shut it down.

Wisdom gratefully received.

Comment: Are you calling `Activity.finish()` anywhere?

Comment: Not calling Activity.finish(), no. Breaking in onDestroy() shows that the activity is being re-launched. I think this might be because it's aspect is changed from landscape to portrait after starting up. This probably explains it. I need to move the executor creation into onCreate() I think. Yep, that's exactly it. I need to start the app in the intended orientation to avoid the problem, as well as moving the executor creation to the onCreate to be safe. Thanks for the input. What does finish() do?

Comment: `finish()` causes `onDestroy()` to be called.  When you rotate your device Android will kill your app and recreate it.  You therefore need to handle such situations to best suit your needs.  Read up on Activity Lifecycle in the API documentation. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() only gets called when your app is being shut down. Here are some things you can try:

1. What happens of you remove the code to shutdown the executor altogether?
2. What happens if you instead move the code to onStop()?
3. Are you sure onStop() is not being called on a previous instance of you app already running on your device. (i.e. you install the app, make changes, install it again, the first one must stop.)

Comment: The problem arose because of an orientation change after the app started. Orientation change re-launches the app forcing it through onDestroy() and then onCreate().